# How to count wordpress posts that have a certain percentual of tags in comon?

Tags: php, wordpress

My posts usually have about 20 tags, and I know that the posts that share 70% percent of the tags with each other are about the same topic. So, is it possible to check it through php and count or list the posts that have tags in comon?

If there's a way, I'd like to know how, so I'd study to acomplish it.

Comment: you should 1) add more details, do you want to just check the posts or do something about it in your site, like showing related posts? 2) Have you tried something already, can post sample code what you've already tried. 3) Does it have to be a php script or sql query will work for you in case you just want to check the data and do something about it offline.

Comment: I just want to count it, to show as data. I have tried, but no way close. I'm only getting ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I will not go into the details of the implementation in PHP, but I can however explain to you how the request you can do in your database to count the number of posts by tag.

There is a "many to many" relationship between posts table (POST) and tags (TAG) which will involve an intermediate table that we can call POST_TAG. So what you can do on POST_TAG is to make a query like this:

```
select tag_id, count(post_id) 
from post_tag
group by tag_id
```